# An implication of the Zagier et al result on the hyperbolicity of Jensen polynomials for the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In their paper recently published in the PNAS, Zagier et al demonstrated that

1. The Jensen polynomials $J_{\alpha}^{d,n}(X)$ of the Riemann zeta function of degree $d$ and shift $n$ are hyperbolic for each $d\geq 1$ and every sufficiently large positive integer $n$.

On page 1 of the paper, they state that

2. if $J_{\alpha}^{d,n}(X)$ is hyperbolic then so is $J_{\alpha}^{d, 0}(X)$, *since the hyperbolicity property is preserved under differentiation."*

On combining (1) and (2), does it follow that $J_{\alpha}^{d,n}(X)$ is hyperbolic for all integers $d\geq 1$ and $n\geq 0$ ?

Comment: I think you are misreading their claim about differentiation, which shows that if $J_\alpha^{d,0}(X)$ is hyperbolic for all $d$, then $J_\alpha^{d,n}(X)$ is hyperbolic for all $d,n$.

Comment: Why is the paper referred to as Zagier et al when Zagier is the fourth author on the paper?

Comment: @Lucia The question-asker wanted to take a stand against alphabetical prejudice?

Comment: @WillSawin:  It gives a different impression I must say.  Now if the other three authors were Zelmanov, Zinoviev and Zywina, I'd understand!

Comment: @Lucia, Zagier is the "fourth" author simply due to alphabetical order. I could have referenced the paper using any one of the author's names, and someone could have asked why I didn't use any of the other three.

Comment: @Wojowu, ah you're right...differentiation increases the shift $n$.

Comment: Could anybody provide a link to the paper (or at least a complete reference)? I haven't even been able to identify it.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07321